# SQL #1066 - Not unique table/alias:

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting this error with my code:

```
SELECT flatpack_ig,FlatpackID ,Name,Colour,Type,UnitPrice,component_ig,ComponentNo, component_ig,
description FROM flatpack_ig
INNER JOIN flatpackcomponent_ig
ON flatpack_ig, FlatpackID= flatpackcomponent_ig,FlatpackID
INNER JOIN component_ig
ON flatpackcomponent_ig, ComponentNo=component_ig,ComponentNo
ORDER BY flatpack_ig,FlatpackID
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have multiple tables in a query, you should *always* qualify *all* column names.  Something like this:

```
SELECT fp.FlatpackID, fp.Name, fp.Colour, fp.Type, fp.UnitPrice,
       c.ComponentNo, c.description
FROM flatpack_ig fp INNER JOIN
     flatpackcomponent_ig fpc
     ON fp.FlatpackID = fpc.FlatpackID INNER JOIN 
     component_ig c INNER JOIN
     flatpackcomponent_ig fpc 
     ON fpc.ComponentNo = c.ComponentNo
ORDER BY fp.FlatpackID;
```

I am guessing where the columns come from.  My guesses may not be accurate.

Your query has multiple other problems as well.  I am guessing that these are transcription errors -- commas instead of periods and misplaced keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution not sure

SELECT flatpack_ig.FlatpackID ,Name,Colour,Type,UnitPrice,component_ig.ComponentNo, component_ig.Description
FROM flatpack_ig
INNER JOIN flatpackcomponent_ig
ON flatpack_ig.FlatpackID= flatpackcomponent_ig.FlatpackID
INNER JOIN component_ig
ON flatpackcomponent_ig.ComponentNo=component_ig.ComponentNo